# Can I have 2 Cronbach's alphas?

Tags: regression, psychometrics

I've got an overall Cronbach's alpha of -.3. The questions are reverse scored. When I calculate 5 out of the 10 questions which have high to low scoring, alpha is .8, and when I find alpha for the other 5 questions, I get alpha .7. But when I do alpha for all 10 questions, it's -.3. I have checked the reverse questions. Can I use .8 and .7, i.e., have 2 alphas?

Comment: Can you more clearly state why exactly you are calculating these $\alpha$'s, and clarify the question title? More background is likely needed to get a response to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse code half the questions before computing alpha. The alpha formula assumes positive correlations all around.